# jquery $ajax get content other html but get it 3 times not just one

Tags: jquery, web

This is the code:

```
$.ajax({
                url:"gegarandeerd.html",
                dataType: "html",
                success: function(data){    
                    $("#content").prepend(data);
                    }   
                });
                $("#content").fadeIn(2000);
        });
```

when i run the code, the html page that it load, comes 3 times on my screen...
when i dont use prepend but just html.(data) it works fine. **someone knows what to do?**

more code:

```
$("a#leesmeer").click(function(){
        var teller = 0;


        $("div#topic").toggle('slide',function(){
        $.ajax({
                url:"gegarandeerd.html",
                dataType: "html",
                success: function(data){    
                        $("#content").prepend(data);
                        alert("1");     
                        }   
                });
                $("#content").slideToggle();    
                });

    });
```

Comment: Have you checked how many times your ajax call is executed? Could be possible that you are performing it multiple times. Please show more code. Which event are you using? Where is the eventhandler bound to the element...

Comment: @DKSan, your answer is almost certainly the right one. Should be posted as an answer.

Comment: @davidethell: Not yet it shouldn't, not until more information is discovered about the question.  As it stands, it's a helpful comment to assist the user is debugging (and potentially finding the answer on his own, which one would hope he would then post here).

Comment: Have you checked how many times your ajax call is executed? Could be possible that you are performing it multiple times. Please show more code. Which event are you using? Where is the eventhandler bound to the element etc.

Comment: I use a click event, and it does call the ajax 3 times, but dont know why...    i edit the code to my question

Answer (score 1):

I think the .js file with that ajax code is called 3 times.. check firebug > Net > Js tab

Answer (score 0):

if in your page jquery.js includes multiple times then also on ajax call apply the number of times you include jquery

so please check your source that how many times jquery includes

Comment: my jquery is in my page, i dont use external .js file for the jquery code

Comment: ya but this can be happen like if u have already include jquery.js in index.php and it includes another test.php file and if you also include jquery.js in test.php then this happens.